# local variable 'Facility' referenced before assignment?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am facing "local variable 'Facility' referenced before assignment". Although I have imported it from Models. I did same thing for many other models to fetch data but this time it gives this error. Please Assist.

Views.py

```
def addshift(request):
        facilities=Facility.objects.order_by('id')
        user=request.user   
        if request.method=="POST":
            StartTime=request.POST.get('StartTime')
            StartDate=request.POST.get('StartDate')
            EndTime=request.POST.get('EndTime')
            EndDate=request.POST.get('EndDate')
            Facility=request.POST.get('Facility')
            Note=request.POST.get('Note')
            shift=Shift(user=request.user,StartTime=StartTime,StartDate=StartDate,EndTime=EndTime,EndDate=EndDate,Facility=Facility,Note=Note)
            shift.save()
            messages.success(request,"Shift added successfully!")
    
        context={
            'schedule':'active',
            'facilities':facilities,
            'user':user,
    
        }
        return render(request,'addshift.html',context)
```

Models.py

```
class Facility(models.Model):
Title=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
FirstName=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
LastName=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
FacilityName=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
FacilityType=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
CorporateGroup=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
LegalName=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
Email=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
Phone=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
FacilityAddress=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.Title + " | " + self.FacilityAddress
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the variable name here cause your model name and this variable name is same.

```
Facility=request.POST.get('Facility')
```

Comment: I had found it out. You have picked it right?